# Possible to add a new class that can be cast to an existing final class?

Tags: java, class, casting, final

I have class A defined in a library:

```
 public final class A {blah}
```

And then I want to hack it somewhere using a new class B to substitute it:

```
A a = new A();  
A a = (A) new B();
```

B has all the methods and members in A, so it's actually safe to do this, and I can do it in C++. But for Java, this casting will result in an exception. So is there any workaround or hacking to do this in Java?
In addition, is there a way to hack without touching the VM?

Comment: Which exception you are getting while casting?

Comment: In java you will get incompatible type casting compiler error, because `B` doesn't extends  `A`(however it can't extends final class).

Comment: Nope nope nope not possible.

Comment: Without any other information, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though `B` has all the methods and property dose `A` have, you can not cast object of `B` to a reference of `A`. That means -

```
A a = (A) new B();
```

is invalid unless `B` extends `A`.

And here `A` is a final class so you can not extends `A` by `B`. You have to make `A` non-final and B has to extends A. Then the above casting will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `final` keyword exists to prevent sub-classing so the simple answer is *no*. You could employ something like [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to do this sort of thing. I wouldn't do it outside of testing though.

Comment: Dose it mean PowerMock allows to extend final class?

Comment: Or dose it mean `PowerMock` allows casting `B` to `A` where `B` and `A` are completely different (Just asking since I don't know about the feature of `PowerMock` )?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. PowerMock implements its own classloader, but I'm actually running on Android. So PowerMock seems not a good idea here, but might be useful somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because your class A is final. A final class is simply a class that can't be extended.